# Efficient generic buffer queue for sequential processing

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, compiler-optimization

I have a producer-consumer queue which is being updated by parallel programs. The queue is queried for various statistics like mean or standard deviation or variance or something else on the current queue contents. For mean, this is the code, I use

```
class BufferQueue {
    const int nMaxQueueSize_;
    int* values;
    int head, tail;
    double sum;
    ::utils::FastMutex queue_mutex;

public:

    BufferQueue(const int nMaxQueueSize) :
    nMaxQueueSize_(nMaxQueueSize) {
        head = tail = 0;
        sum = 0;
        values = new int[nMaxQueueSize_];
    }

    void enqueue(int val) {
        values[head] = val;
        if ((head + 1) % nMaxQueueSize_ == tail) {
            queue_mutex.lock();
            sum = val.value_point - values[tail].value_point;
            utils::memory_barrier();
            head = (1 + head) % nMaxQueueSize_;
            tail = (1 + tail) % nMaxQueueSize_;
            queue_mutex.unlock();
        } else {
            queue_mutex.lock();
            sum += val.value_point;
            utils::memory_barrier();
            head = (1 + head) % nMaxQueueSize_;
            queue_mutex.unlock();
        }
    }

    bool dequeue() {
        if (head != tail) {
            queue_mutex.lock();
            sum -= values[tail].value_point;
            utils::memory_barrier();
            tail = (1 + tail) % nMaxQueueSize_;
            queue_mutex.unlock();
            return true;
        } else {
            sum = 0;
            return false;
        }
    }

    MarketSpreadPoint& operator[](int i) {
        return values[ (tail + i) % nMaxQueueSize_ ];
    }

    inline int getSize() {
        return (head - tail + nMaxQueueSize_) % nMaxQueueSize_;
    }

    inline double average() {
        queue_mutex.lock();
        double result = sum / getSize();
        queue_mutex.unlock();
        return result;
    }

    ~BufferQueue() {
        delete values;
    }
};
```

**NOTE**: One important thing to remember is that only one operation is being performed. Neither do I want to repeat code by writing separate implementations like ***BufferQueueAverage***, ***BufferQueueVariance*** etc. I want very limit code redundancy(compiler optimizations). Even conditioning on type of queue for every update seems sub-optimal.

```
    inline double average() {
        queue_mutex.lock();
        if(type_is_average){
            double result = sum / getSize();
        }else if(type_is_variance){
            /// update accordingly.
        }
        double result = sum / getSize();
        queue_mutex.unlock();
        return result;
    }
```

What can be a good alternative to this idea ?

***Note***: In this implementation, if queue is full, head automatically make the tail to move forward. In other words, the oldest element is deleted automatically.

Thanks

Comment: What is that `int* values = new MarketSpreadPoint[nMaxQueueSize_];` ?

Comment: @DieterLücking, sorry , corrected

Comment: Your queue is not thread-safe. I say this because your code looks like you are trying to make it so, but it is flawed. Both `enqueue` and `dequeue` have race conditions.

Comment: @Smeeheey, Can you please elaborate? Please give any scenario, where it fails ?

Comment: 1). In `enqueue` you do `values[head] = val;` without locks. Two threads could do this simultaneously thus writing into the same slot twice. 2). In `dequeue` you do the `if(head != tail)` check without locks. Again two threads could come along and do this check simultaneously, both moving on to `queue_muteck.lock();` - even though they will not both do the locked section concurrently they will both do it, so if the queue had only 1 element left when they entered that's a problem. That's not an exhaustive list of all that's wrong BTW

Comment: @Smeeheey, I am sorry for the ambiguity. But my queue is single producer single consumer one. Only one thread populates the queue while only one thread can dequeue elements concurrently from it. Considering this usage, Is there anything else wrong in the implementation. My main target is to perform perform various statistics operations on the stream efficiently and accurately. Please reply back..

Comment: Suppose consumer and producer arrive simultaneously to enqueue and dequeue, and both pass their first `if` check with `true` result, then `dequeue` gets the lock first. It decrements `sum` and increments `tail`. Next, `enqueue` gets the lock. It is still in the section for handling a full queue, even though the queue is not full anymore. It needlessly removes the `tail` value again, both from the sum and the queue.

Comment: Another one: suppose the queue is full and `enqueue` is called, and gets the lock. Having just incremented `head`, it is just about to increment `tail` when `dequeue` is called. Because this checks `head != tail` without the lock and because `head` has already been incremented but not `tail`, it will see a false result and thus set `sum` to zero even though the queue is full.

Comment: More generally, reading/writing non-atomic variables from multiple threads without sequencing/synchronisation mechanisms (as you do here) is technically undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to separate the queue from the statistics. I see two possible solutions:

1. Use a pattern like *Template Method* or *Strategy* to factor out the dependency.
2. Use a template that does this.

Assuming that all statistics you gather can [gathered incrementally](http://nfs-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~fanf2/hermes/doc/antiforgery/stats.pdf), the latter could look similar to the following (just meant as pseudo code):

```
class StatisticsMean
{
private:
    int n = 0;
    double mean = 0.0;
public: 
    void addSample(int s) { ++n; mean += (s - mean) / n; }
    void removeSample(int s) { ... }
    double getStatistic() const { return mean; }
}

template <typename TStatistics>
class BufferQueue 
{
    TStatistics statistics;
    ...

    void enqueue(int val) 
    {
        ...
        statistics.addSample(val);
    }
    ...
    double getStatistic() const { return statistics.getStatistic(); }
}
```

The template approach gives you full compile-time optimization. You can achieve the same with the *Template Method* pattern. This would also allow you to have distinct names for the getters (`getStatistic()` in the above example).

This could look similar to this:

```
class AbstractBufferQueue 
{
    virtual void addSample(int s) = 0;
    virtual void removeSample(int s) = 0;

    void enqueue(int val) 
    {
        ...
        addSample(val);
    }
}

class BufferQueueAverage : public AbstractBufferQueue
{
    int n;
    double mean;

    void addSample(int s) { ++n; mean += (s - mean) / n; }
    void removeSample(int s) { ... }
    double getAverage() const { return mean; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you're asking is by using template classes.

First, decide on a common interface that an *accumulator* will have. It might be something like:

```
class accumulator
{
public:
    typedef double value_type;

public:
    void push(int v); // Called when pushing a new value.
    void pop(int v); // Called when popping a new value;
    value_type result(size_t n) const; // Returns the current accumulation.
};
```

As a special case, `mean_accumulator` could be this:

```
class mean_accumulator
{
public:
    typedef double value_type;

public:
    mean_accumulator() : m_sum{0} {}

    void push(int v) { m_sum += v; }
    void pop(int v); { m_sum -= v; }
    double result(size_t n) const { return m_sum / n; };

private:
    int m_sum;
};
```

Now, parameterize your queue by `Accumulator`, and call it when necessary (while you're at it, note that [`boost::circular_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_circular_buffer_c___reference.html#header.boost.circular_buffer_hpp) has much of what you need for the implementation:

```
template<class Accumulator>
class queue
{
private:
    boost::circular_buffer<int> m_buf;
    std::mutex m_m;

public:
    void push(int v) 
    {
       // Lock the mutex, push to the circular buffer, and the accumulator
    }

    bool pop() 
    {
       // Lock the mutex; if relevant, update the accumulator and pop the circular buffer
    }

    typename Accumulator::value_type result() const
    {
       // Lock the mutex and return the accumulator's result.
    }
};
```